CdkVirtualScrollViewport inside MatDialog not working as expected
I'm trying to display the contents of a file inside a MatDialog using CdkVirtualScrollViewport
The template for my MatDialog is the following:
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport style="height: 100%" [itemSize]="20">
  <ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let item of remoteFileDataSource">
    <pre class="file-line-item">{{ item }}</pre>
  </ng-container>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>

I'm using a custom DataSource which is a copy of the example given by the Angular Material docs. The only difference being, my DataSource makes a call to a backend to get a subset of lines from the file.
export class RemoteFileDataSource extends DataSource<string | undefined> {
  private _length = 100000;
  private _pageSize = 100;
  private _cachedData = Array.from<string>({length: this._length});
  private _fetchedPages = new Set<number>();
  private readonly _dataStream = new BehaviorSubject<(string | undefined)[]>(this._cachedData);
  private readonly _subscription = new Subscription();

  connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<(string | undefined)[]> {
    this._subscription.add(
      collectionViewer.viewChange.subscribe(range => {
        const startPage = this._getPageForIndex(range.start);
        const endPage = this._getPageForIndex(range.end - 1);
        for (let i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++) {
          this._fetchPage(i);
        }
      }),
    );
    return this._dataStream;
  }

  disconnect(): void {
    this._subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  private _getPageForIndex(index: number): number {
    return Math.floor(index / this._pageSize);
  }

  private _fetchPage(page: number) {
    if (this._fetchedPages.has(page)) {
      return;
    }
    this._fetchedPages.add(page);

    httpCall().pipe(tap(value: string[]) => {
        this._cachedData.splice(
          page * this._pageSize,
          this._pageSize,
          ...value,
        );
        this._dataStream.next(this._cachedData);
      })).subscribe(),
    );
  }
}

The file I'm using has over 4M lines and we're fetching 1000 lines from the file at a time. The issue is when I scroll to the bottom of the viewport I should be getting the end of the file, instead I'm still nowhere near the end.
At the end of the scroll, the DataSource is calculating the range as:
{
    "start": 1677623,
    "end": 1677732
}

which equates to page 1677. 1677 * 1000 is 1,677,000 which means I'm still only somewhere near the top half of the file.
The cdk-virtual-scroll-spacer seems to have the correct height:
<div class="cdk-virtual-scroll-spacer" style="height: 8.06451e+07px;"></div>

Which if you take 80645100 and divide it by 20 (which is the height of each element in the scroll) you get 4,032,255 and my file has 4,032,253 lines.
So it seems that the collectionViewer.viewChange method is receiving the wrong range information or I'm calculating the start and end page incorrectly.
